# Android ParseObject revert unsaved changed to LocalStore object

Tags: android, parsing, local-datastore

I`m using Parse localdata store objects, and i`m wondering how to perform revert to unpinned changes on that object. for example i have and object Kid which is a ParseObject

```
Kid k = new Kid();
k.setName("name1")
k.pin();

k.setName("name2");
k.revertlocalChanges()?
```

so k.getName() will return the original name and any other query to localdatastore will return previous value

Comment: I'm running into the same problem... very frustrating.